# Django runs fine locally but one field doesn't exist after deploying to Heroku

Tags: django, database, heroku, deployment, model

I'm still relatively new to django. In my website, I created a new field `group` in `AnonymousStudent` model. My Django website runs fine on my local machine, but after deploying to Heroku it says the group field doesn't exist.

I got couple of errors when trying to access to different parts in my website. 
One says:

```
ProgrammingError at ...
column "group" of relation "student_anonymousstudent" does not exist LINE 1: ...", "last_active_time", "associate_experiment_id", "group") V...
```

Another one says:

```
ProgrammingError at ...
column student_anonymousstudent.group does not exist LINE 1: ...dent_anonymousstudent"."associate_experiment_id", "student_a...
```

And the other one says:

```
InvalidCursorName at ...
cursor "_django_curs_139758823008000_sync_1" does not exist
```

The traceback for the last one says:

```
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py in _execute
86.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
▶ Local vars
The above exception (column student_anonymousstudent.group does not exist LINE 1: ...dent_anonymousstudent"."associate_experiment_id", "student_a... ^ ) was the direct cause of the following exception: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py in execute_sql
1144.             cursor.execute(sql, params)
```

It seems like a migration problem, but when I tried to run `python manage.py makemigrations` it says nothing changed.

**settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3')
    }
}

if 'HEROKU_ENV' in os.environ:
    ALLOWED_HOSTS.append(".herokuapp.com")
    DATABASES["default"] = dj_database_url.config(
        ssl_require=True,
        engine="django_postgrespool2"
    )
```

**Procfile**

```
release: bash release-tasks.sh
web: daphne giks.asgi:application -b 0.0.0.0 -p $PORT -v2
```

**release-tasks.sh**

```
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py loaddata fixtures/publications.json
python manage.py loaddata fixtures/awards.json
```

I have couple of questions here:

1. Apparently I'm using two different databases for local and Heroku environments. But I've specified in my `Procfile` to auto run migrations when deploying. So is this really a migration problem?
2. Still about the database. Can you use `django_postgrespool2` with `sqlite3`?
3. What exactly is the problem? And how to fix it?

Please let me know if more information is needed. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is `HEROKU_ENV` being picked up correctly when the migrations are run? If you get log output when the migration is run you could add a print in your settings

Comment: @IainShelvington, thank you for the comment and sorry for the late reply. I did what you suggested, I think it got picked up correctly (if I didn't do it wrong...) because it's printing the stuff that I added in the settings file under the `HEROKU_ENV` if statement.